# How to use multiple CSS files in Meteor

Tags: css, meteor

I've started using meteor and want to know what is a good way to migrate a HTML file that refers to many CSS files. So far, I found that meteor will automatically load all CSS files in an alphabetic order. My two questions are as follows:

1. Where should I locate the CSS files? (or from where I can control which directories are loaded)
2. Is it possible to load specific CSS files in particular order?

Here are the current references I have in my HTML file, before migrating to meteor.

```
    <!-- Web Fonts  -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800|Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Libs CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" media="screen">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-elements.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-animate.css">

    <!-- Current Page Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/circle-flip-slideshow/css/component.css" media="screen">

    <!-- Skin CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skins/blue.css">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

    <!-- Responsive CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-responsive.css" />
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: you can put your css files anywhere. The load order is described in docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Answer (score 34):

There is no need to provide reference of stylesheets in meteor. Just put your css file in client/stylesheets folder. Meteor will automatically apply these css rules.

Answer (score 8):

As stated by @imslavko you can find Meteor behaviour at https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

However these rules are more relevant for `.js` code and `.html`template files: Meteor merge and minimize all `.css` in a single file (as long as they are provided by you and not on a CDN) so you will find a single `<link rel="stylesheet">` reference in your `<head>`.

Remember to put all frontend files inside `client` folder, to avoid unnecessary server loading and availability.

So you can choose your convenient folder structure for `.css` files, for example put them all in `client/stylesheets` or use other subfolders to better manage them.

Comment: What about placement of certain JS files. I like to have my custom js file in the footer as apposed to the header area of my app. How can one accomplish that?